# Getting a VPN to use a NAT Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, vpn, iptables, nat

I want to create a VPN instance where:

1) Clients can connect over a public IP

2) All outgoing connections happen over a NAT gateway

To illustrate:

[image: Networking description]

We want to do this because our NAT gateway IP addresses are whitelisted by vendors and it would make local development really easy.

I think the right answer involves configuring IPTables to use a source NAT, but I'm not sure about the details.

Another option might be to set a load balancer in front of OpenVPN? But everything I've read seems to indicate that OpenVPN isn't compatible with load balancing.

Comment: Do you use any software like PfSense in your router? That would make the whole thing a lot easier I guess.

Comment: Nope - the NAT gateways are managed by AWS and talk to an IGW.

Comment: Which type of VPN do you use? AWS managed site-to-site VPN, AWS managed client VPN or a custom OpenVPN-like solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you use the AWS managed client VPN service called *AWS Client VPN*, you should be able to do this. The configuration is outlined in the docs [1]. Just use the NAT Gateway instead of the Internet Gateway in step 5.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/scenario-internet.html

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant. I had tried earlier, but I didn't think I could associate a private subnet.